# Extended Euclidean Division and Series

Tags: real-numbers

We know that the extended Euclidean division of 8 by 3 results in the periodic decimal number 2,666 ...
We can also see that the series indicated by the decimal number, this is, 2 + 6/10 + 6/100 + 6/1000 + ... converges to 8/3.
Let a and b be positive integers, with a> b. Suppose that the extended Euclidean division of a by b results in a periodic decimal number (simple or compound). How can we prove that the series indicated by this decimal number converges to a / b?
I need help.

Comment: I don't know where you're stuck, but if I had to guess it's this: With, for instance, $\frac2{11} = 0.18181818\ldots$, don't use $1/10 + 8/100 + 1/1000 + 8/10\,000 + \cdots$, but use $18/100 + 18/10\,000 + 18/1000\,000 + \cdots$ instead.

Comment: My difficulty lies in generalization.